# Hub Navigation on Mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site, mobile-view

so I have a hub site and another site that is connected to that hub site. When navigating through desktop browser, I have no problem navigating through the hub site and the connected site. However when opening the connected site in a mobile browser (chrome on Android), the link that takes me back to the hub site is missing, and will appear when I refresh the page. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening, so the link to the hub site will always appear on mobile navigation? Thanks before!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much we can configure when it comes to mobile view. The (Hub) navigation is displayed automatically and there are no extra settings for it on mobile.

I would suggest you use the [SharePoint Online mobile app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stay-connected-with-the-sharepoint-mobile-app-92b93131-fbef-4894-8ba2-2fdfa90c5b32) though. The hub navigation is working properly on the app, per my recent test.